# Bootstrap Modal Always Active

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Could I keep bootstrap modal always active ? Can anyone help me ?

JavaScript of the modal as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '#add-subject', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        bootbox.prompt("Enter New Subject", function (result) {
            if (result !== null && result !== '') {
                $('#subject_id').append('<option>' + result + '</option>')
                    .val(result);
                $("#subject_id").val(result).trigger("change");
            }

        });

    });
    
</script>
```

Comment: please explain what you mean *keep bootstrap modal always active*: do you want that it shows always, never closes, even after data inserted (change event)?

Comment: There are large no. of records to be inserted at the start. Therefore, it is easy to keep modal active till finish record inserting. No need to shows always. Needs to close when press window close button.